# Efficiently progressively filtering large dataset in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-bigquery

I have app that allows users to build queries that are run against a fairly large database (15 million records). The user is able to filter on about 45 different fields. They create these filters by first picking a field from a drop-down and then selecting values from an addition drop-down that is populated based on the field selection. I would like to make this progressively filtered similarly to how excel works. Additional filters should be limited to the data available after the prior filters are applied. This may also limit the available fields as well. Right now I can make this work but only by reaching out to the entire table to get options for each selected field. As you might imagine this is not very efficient as I keep reprocessing the same data over and over. My data is in google big query. The server is node running express. Is there some other way that I can do this that is more efficient but still drive the progressive filter behavior? I have looked around but the only things I can find is doing this on a large dataset in memory but I need to do this as server requests.

Any ideas would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating the CPU extensive task to `worker` threads in js.

Can have a look at [Napa.js](https://github.com/microsoft/napajs)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think more of what I'm looking for is really is there a data structure to hold all the possible option combinations in that would be better than hitting the entire database each time?